# Помогите написать запрос на sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Здравствуйте, есть три таблицы User, Place, Sales:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Place(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    sales = db.relationship('Sales', backref='place', lazy='dynamic')

    def regular_clients(self, time_start, time_end):
        pass

class Sales(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    place_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('place.id'))    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    buyer = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[user_id])
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False),default=datetime.utcnow)
    sum = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

Необходимо посчитать постоянных клиентов на точке Place за определенный промежуток времени, клиент считается "постоянным", если, например, он сделал 5 покупок за временной промежуток.

В классе Place начал описывать метод:

```
def regular_clients(self, time_start, time_end):
    query = db.session.query(User).join(Sales.user_id).\
        filter(Sales.place_id == self.id,
               Sales.timestamp >= date_start, Sales.timestamp <= date_end)
```

Но как добавить фильтр по количеству покупок, помогите плиз, написать запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал:

```
amoun = db.session.query(User).join(Sales.buyer).\
        filter(Sales.place_id == self.id,
               Sales.timestamp >= time_start,
               Sales.timestamp <= time_end).\
        group_by(User.id).\
        having(db.func.count(Sales.id) >= 5).count()
```